# VPN is stopping during network is switching from wifi to mobile data. VPN is connected programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, vpn, nevpnmanager

I am using Network Extension framework for configure and connect VPN server programmatically. I can start and stop VPN. I have written following code to configure VPN in viewDidLoad.

```
NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
[manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

        if(manager.protocol == nil)
        {
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"VPNCert" ofType:@"p12"];
            NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            NSString *certPassword = @"password";

            NSString *vpnUsername = @"username";
            NSString *vpnPassword = @"password";
            NSString *vpnUrl = @"VPN Server IP";

            // This saves my credentials to the keychain and returns a persistent keychain reference
            NSData *passRef = [self addVPNCredentialsToKeychain:vpnUsername withPassword:vpnPassword];

            NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
            p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodCertificate;
            p.serverAddress = vpnUrl;
            p.username = vpnUsername;
            p.passwordReference = passRef;
            p.identityData = certData;
            p.identityDataPassword = certPassword;
            p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
            p.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;

            manager.protocol = p;
            manager.enabled = YES;
            [manager setOnDemandEnabled:NO];
            [manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VPN Network"];
            [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                if(error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Load error: %@", error);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```

I also wrote code for start VPN when button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
    [manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                if (!error)
                {
                    NSError *startError = [[NSError alloc] init];
                    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];
                }
            }];
}
```

Cases working for me.

1. If i connect VPN in mobile data and switched to wifi this case VPN is not disconnecting.
2. Also working if i connect VPN in mobile data and switched to wifi and then back to mobile data VPN is not disconnecting.

Problem is

If i connect VPN in wifi and then switch to mobile data, in this case VPN is stopping. I want VPN must stop only when user will stop the VPN.

Is any steps are missing while configuring VPN because of that VPN is stopping?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add rules to keep the connection persisted. Also enable onDemand  [manager setOnDemandEnabled:YES];

**Swift**

```
    let connectRule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
    connectRule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any

    let disconnectRule = NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect()
    disconnectRule.probeURL = URL(string:VPNCredentialsModel.instance.vpnProbeURL()!)
```

Comment: Don't you have to listen for defaultPath changes using KVO to trigger a reconnection?